# Update row where associated row does not exist

Tags: oracle, merge

Given the table named ROLE:

```
role_id[PK] NUMBER
role_name   VARCHAR2
```

Using only SQL (no PL/SQL) how would I write a MERGE (or UPDATE?) statement that would update the role_name as below, but only for rows where another row with the new role_name does not already exist? (By "new role_name" I mean `'prefix-' || role_name`)

```
UPDATE role
SET role_name = 'prefix-' || role_name
WHERE role_name LIKE 'com.example.%';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the predicate:

```
 AND NOT EXISTS (
 SELECT 1 FROM role AS r_existing 
 WHERE r_existing.role_name = 'prefix-' || role.role_name)
```

Comment: Is not exists better than not in? Or are they equivalent?

Comment: They’re nearly equivalent, depending on conditions. Ideally they get executed the same way. Null values can confuse matters though, so I prefer “not exists”.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was able to manage:

```
MERGE INTO ROLE A USING
 (SELECT
      role_id,
      role_name,
      'prefix-' || role_name as new_role_name
  FROM ROLE r
  WHERE role_name LIKE 'com.example.%'
    AND not exists (
        SELECT 1
        FROM ROLE r2
        WHERE r2.role_name = 'prefix-' || r.role_name)
  ) B
ON (A.ROLE_id = B.ROLE_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET 
  A.ROLE_NAME = B.NEW_ROLE_NAME;
```